# findHomography usage opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, motion-detection

I am using opencv c++ and am a new user. I am interested in object detection problems . So far I have studies and implemented the use of sparse optical flow( Lucas Kanade method) in a video from a stationary camera.After trying k means and Background substraction , I have decided to move to a more difficult problem , that is the moving camera.

I have so far studied some documentation and found out that I could use cv::findHomography in order to find the inliers or outliers during the sequence of frames in my video and then understand from the returned values what movement is caused due to camera motion and what due to object motion. In addition , I could use SURF features to track some objects and then decide which of them are good points .

However , I was wondering how I could implement this theory. For example, should I use the first frame as ground truth and detect some features using SURF and then for the rest of the video use findHomography for each frame ? Any ideas/help is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting moving objects from moving camera is a quite challenging task, and requires solid understanding of multiple view geometry, besides there is less info on this topic available (than, for example, about structure from motion), so be warned!

Anyway, homography matrix will not be a good choice for detection of moving objects (unless you are 100% sure that your background can be represented by a flat surface accurately enough). You should probably use a fundamental matrix or trifocal tensor.

[Fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) is computed from point correspondences between 2 frames. It associates points on one image with lines on other image (so called epipolar lines), and this way it is independent from scene structure. After you have obtained F matrix using some robust estimation method, like [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) or [LMEDS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/INRIA/Publis/Tutorial-Estim/node25.html) (RANSAC seems to be better for this kind of task), you can calculate the reprojection error for each point. Objects that move independently from scene would not be accurately described by F matrix and will have a bigger error. So, outliers of F matrix calculated from image matches over two frames can be considered moving objects. One note though - objects that move along epipolar lines would not be detected by this approach, since their parallax can be also described by some depth level.

[Trifocal tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifocal_tensor) does not have the depth/motion ambiguity with objects that move along epipolar lines, but it is harder to estimate and it is not included into OpenCV. It can be calculated from correspondences over 3 frames, and its usage can be conceptually described as triangulating a point from 2 views and then calculating reprojection error on a third view.

As for the matching - I still think that [LK tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method) will be better than SURF matching if you work with video sequences, since in that case you don't need to consider very distant points as matches, and tracking usually is faster then detection+matching.

Comment: Very analytic answer thank you very much ! I am working with this project in order to do my master thesis so I do not care too much about the accuracy of tracking , I just want to try several methods and find the best.
Besides , can you explain the difference between the matrix of findHomography and the fundamental matrix ? Are they not the same ?

Comment: No, they are not the same. Homography associates points with points (usually, although you can use it for line and plane correspondences), fundamental matrix - points with lines. Homography works for planes, fundamental matrix - for arbitrary rigid bodies. Homography has 8 degrees of freedom, fundamental matrix - 7. I guess one can find more differences.